# Class 'Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient' not found

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, bolt-cms

I've autoloaded the Facebook sdk classes with composer. Here's the composer `autoload_psr4.php`:

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Facebook\\' => array($vendorDir . '/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook'),
    'Bolt\\Extension\\radix\\facebook\\' => array($baseDir . '/'),
);
```

And in my code, I'm using the various classes:

```
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\GraphUser;

class Extension extends BaseExtension
{

    public function initialize() {

        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('zzzz','zzzzzzz');
        $session = new FacebookSession('zzzzz');

        $this->app->get("test", function () use ($session){
            $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/2342342342323432/events');
            $response = $request->execute();
            $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

            $response = $this->app->json($graphObject);
            return $response;
        });
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return "facebook";
    }

}
```

But I get the above error when hitting that route. The class definitely exists in the autoloaded folder, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Can anyone shed light?

Comment: It should work, have you tried clean the cache?

Comment: I've just cleared the cache and have done `dump-autoload` again - still the same result.